# importing module from current folder in hy

Tags: hy

Has import changed in Hy version 1.0a4+199.g22021c56?
I'm trying to import a file from the same folder (or cwd), but I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thenameofthefile'

Even if I append current path to sys.path.

This is how you can reproduce it.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "(defn doit[] (print \"something\"))" > printsomething.hy

echo "(import printsomething [doit])" > callit.hy
echo "(doit printsomething)" >> callit.hy

hy callit.hy
```

Comment: Try providing a reproducible example, such as a shell script that sets up your situation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Some parentheses were missing from the file to be imported... I could not import it because it did not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the above produces `NameError: name 'printsomething' is not defined`. The problem is that `doit` is imported selectively, so the name `printsomething` is not bound to the whole module. To get both a selective import and the whole module, you need

```
(import  printsomething [doit]  printsomething)
```

or in Python

```
from printsomething import doit
import printsomething
```

Note that this will still crash, since `doit() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`.